# Jquery get position in percentage of mouseclick in element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I get the position of the cursor in percentage? I tried this so far.

```js
$(".outter").click(function(e) {
  var perc = e.offsetX / $(this).width() * 100;

  if (perc > 100)
    perc = 100;

  $(this).children(".progress").css("width", perc + "%");
});

$(".outter").dblclick(function(e) {
  $(this).children(".progress").css("width", "100%");
});
```

```css
.outter {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33.33%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
}
.outter > .content {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
.outter > .progress {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #29B6AC;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outter">
  <div class="content">
    Some content...
  </div>
  <div class="progress"></div>
</div>
```

My problem is, that the value inside `perc` isn't correct. In the middle at about 50% it seems like ok. But if you click at about 10% od 90% you can see the backgroundbar won't stop at your cursor position. What did I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.outter` div has a `padding` of `10px`, and since you are using jquery's `.width()` which will not include those 20 pixels.

You can either can get rid of the padding or you can use [`.outerWidth()`](http://api.jquery.com/outerwidth/) to get the correct size.

Comment: Thanks for the answer: I tried it with `.outerWidth()`, but it had some issues too. When I am using `var perc = (e.pageX - this.offsetLeft) / $(this).outerWidth() * 100;` it works perfect! Thanks for the hint with the padding.

Answer (score 2):

Your padding css on the outter class messed up the offsetX module, try setting the padding to 0px and everything will work as intended... read on the [offsetX API/doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/offsetX)

Answer (score 1):

The calculation should be something like:
    
    `$(".outter").click(function(e) {
        var parentOffset = $(this).parent().offset();
        var relX = e.pageX - parentOffset.left;
        var perc = relX / $(this).width() * 100;
        ...`